# How do you shuffle a string in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart lists have a `.shuffle()` method that rearranges the items in a random order. Is there an easy way to shuffle characters in a string like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of using `String.split('')` on Unicode strings if you're going to rearrange elements in the resulting `List`. `split('')` will split a `String` on UTF-16 code *unit* boundaries.  For example, `'\u{1F4A9}'.split('')` will return a `List` of two elements, and rearranging them and recombining them will result in a broken string.

Using [`String.runes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/runes.html) would work a bit better by splitting on Unicode code *points*:

```dart
extension Shuffle on String {
  String get shuffled => String.fromCharCodes(runes.toList()..shuffle());
}
```

Even better would be to use [`package:characters`](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) to operate on *grapheme clusters*:

```dart
extension Shuffle on String {
  String get shuffled => (characters.toList()..shuffle()).join();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.shuffle()` list method modifies a list so that its elements are in a random order. Unlike lists, string are immutable in Dart, so it's impossible to have a `.shuffle()` method for strings that does the same thing.

Luckily, you can just use a function that *returns* a shuffled string to get the same effect:

```dart
extension Shuffle on String {
  /// Strings are [immutable], so this getter returns a shuffled string
  /// rather than modifying the original.
  String get shuffled => (split('')..shuffle()).join('');
}
```

Here it is in action:

```dart
final list = [1, 2, 3];
list.shuffle(); // list is now in random order

var str = 'abc';
str = str.shuffled; // str is now in random order
```

Comment: This won't work well on Unicode strings.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776792/) for better approaches.